# How do I put content from a specific node next to a grid view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to place a body of text alongside a dynamically generated grid of product images.

I can easily create the grid using the Views module - but how do I split a page to display a specify page node alongside the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you might do it. The best way may depend on the particulars of your layout.

One solution would be to use the [Panels module](https://drupal.org/project/panels).

Or you could override the default page.tpl.php with something like page-node-1.tpl.php and insert the view using [views_embed_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/6).

Yet another method would be to output the view as a block display and add it to a block region on the node page.

Comment: Panels module does the job quite nicely, thanks - I prefer to be able to do this within the administration of the site rather than forcing it by template.

Answer (score 1):

Views Attach module may also help.